# How to pass values checked inside a cell in a table returned from one ajax call to another ajax call ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My first JavaScript named DisplayFruitToOrder() makes an Ajax call that returns table with fruits info. I want to display check box by the side of fruit name if it is either Apple, Orange, or Banana. After displaying the table in HTML, user will mark the check box to order either of those 3 fruits, and click Order Fruit button. After clicking Order Fruit button, I want to trigger another JavaScript function called orderFruit() which will make another Ajax call to order the fruits selected by users. I completed the displaying check box by the side of fruit name part, but I am stuck in second part i.e. ordering only the marked ones from either Apple, Orange, or Banana. How can I pass checked value inside a cell in the table returned from one Ajax call to Another? I have attached image of sample table generated from first Ajax call from first JavaScript function. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CBCy.jpg)

```js
var fruitToOrder = "None";

function DisplayFruitToOrder() {
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/listFruits",

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            resultLen = Object.keys(data).length;
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < resultLen; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + data.FruitNumber + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + data.FruitColor + "</td>");
                if (data.FruitName == "Apple" || "Orange" || "Banana") {
                    tr.append("<td>" + data.FruitName + " <input type='checkbox' />" + "</td>");
                    fruitToOrder = data.FruitName;
                } else {
                    tr.append("<td>" + data.FruitName + "</td>");
                    fruitToOrder = 0;
                }
                tr.append("<td>" + data.FruitShape + "</td>");
                $('table').append(tr);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // handle your fail response here       
            console.log("Unknown error occured. Unsuccessful in getting response.");
        }
    }); //end of ajax 
} //end of DisplayFruitToOrder() function

function orderFruit() {
    console.log("Fruit to order is: " + fruitToOrder);
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/orderFruit?fruitName=" + fruitToOrder,

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log("Unknown error occured. Unsuccessful in getting response.");
        }
    }); //end of ajax 
} //end of orderFruit() function
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
  </head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  table {
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 100%;
  }

  td, th {
   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #dddddd;
  }
 </style>
  <head>
  <body onload="DisplayFruitToOrder()">
  
  <div id="divTable" >
  <table>
    <tr>
   <th>FruitNumber</th>
   <th>FruitColor</th>
   <th>FruitName</th>
   <th>FruitShape</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
 <br>
 </div>
 
 <div id="orderFruit" class="container">
     <br>
  <input type="button" value="Order Fruit" onclick="orderFruit()" />
  <br> 
 </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a class name for all checkbox and data attribute like,

```
tr.append("<td>" + data.FruitName + " <input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' data-fruit='"+data.FruitName+"' /></td>");
```

Then in button click,

```
function orderFruit() {
var fruitToOrder = "";

$('.chkbx:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
fruitToOrder = fruitToOrder + $(this).attr("data-fruit") + ",";
});
    console.log("Fruit to order is: " + fruitToOrder);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can order only one at a time. So for example if user selected Apple, and Banana then I will have to make two Ajax calls. For ordering apple, the url will be "http://localhost:5000/orderFruit?fruitName=Apple", and for banana, the url will be "http://localhost:5000/orderFruit?fruitName=Banana. How can achieve this ? I am very very new to Ajax and Javascript.

Comment: First thing calling ajax each time is not the correct way. You have to change the orderFruit page to order multiple fruits.

Comment: Second thing if it is not possible call ajax function inside each loop $('.chkbx:checkbox:checked').each(function(){

Comment: Until orderFruit page is able to handle multiple order, I guess creating an array and looping through that array would be a workaround for now ? Like:-

function orderFruit() {
var fruitToOrderArray = "";

$('.chkbx:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
fruitToOrderArray = fruitToOrderArray + $(this).attr("data-fruit") + ",";
});
    console.log("Fruit to order is: " + fruitToOrder); 
for(int i=0; i<fruitToOrderArray.length; i++ ){
localhost:5000/orderFruit?fruitName=fruitToOrderArray[i];
}}

Comment: Adding array and another loop will increase unnecessary processing. You can call ajax from each loop itself. Also your javascript array code is not correct.

Comment: I will try to make orderFruit able to handle multiple order, but I am trying to check workaround for temporary period. In the latest comment you recommended to make ajax call from each loop itself, but in above comment you said it is not possible to call ajax function inside each loop $('.chkbx:checkbox:checked').each(function(){, so which one is true ?